# I lost a door lock wire inside the door

Tags: locks, door

I was refitting repaired door lock and accidentally the wire that is used to push down the lever on the actuator (?) fell inside the door. I can hear it rattling somewhere in the corner but I have no idea how to get it out. My car is Peugeot 607. I just didn't think this could happen since doors are hollow but apparently not?.. Is there someway I can get it out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With difficulty ;)

Remove the door card (interior trim) if it's not off already - this should reveal a number of holes in the inner skin of the door.

Using a small mirror and a torch, try to work out where the wire has gone - it'll probably be in the most inconvenient place possible!

You'll then need to use something to try and grab it - I'd recommend a [Flexible claw](https://www.amazon.co.uk/600mm-FLEXIBLE-CLAW-LIFTING/dp/B00439FN06) as that should enable you to get some kind of grip on it...

Good luck!

Comment: You can also try a telescoping magnet pickup tool, which are generally cheaper, that is of course assuming the wire is ferous. The magnet will stick to the door too, but with enough wiggling around it should find the intended target. If the hole in the door is big enough, you can shoot a video with your phone to try and locate the wire. Also, to clarify for us improper English speakers: torch = flashlight. Unless you want to cut a hole in the door, then torch = blowtorch :P

Comment: The magnet sticking to the door is why I didn't suggest it! Cutting a hole in the door would be a much quicker way of getting it out, but rather more destructive...